# Corona SDK audio not working on Android

Tags: android, audio, lua, coronasdk

I am currently working on a small game in Corona SDK. I have recently began adding audio/sound-fx to the game. All the audio works fine on the simulator, on my PC, and on my tablet. However, when I play the game on my Galaxy s7 the audio simply doesn't do anything.

Here is what I am using:

```
local function onLoginBtnRelease()
    local btnpressSound = audio.loadStream( "/assets/Audio/FX/buttonpress.mp3" )
    local btnpressSoundChannel = audio.play( btnpressSound, { channel=3} )
end

local loginBtn = widget.newButton{
    textOnly = true,
    defaultFile="assets/playbtn.png",
    width=130,
    height=60,
    onRelease = onLoginBtnRelease,
}
loginBtn.x = 440
loginBtn.y = display.contentHeight -160
sceneGroup:insert(loginBtn)
```

and just in case this could be an issue that i'm not seeing or knowing could effect Android, here is a screenshot of the mp3 file path
[MP3 File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnQbg.png)

I have searched and searched all over and I simply cannot find a solution to this issue. From everything I can see, this should be working fine in Android. It works great on the simulator, my PC, and my tablet...  Any help with what I may not be thinking about or am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

edit: BTW, I have tested this on 5 different Android devices. 2 s7's, 1 s5, and 2 s3's.

edit2: I have tried placing the audio in the root folder and changing the file path and that also did not work...  =(

edit3: I have tried wav, mp3, & ogg; all with the same results.

Comment: Hey please share your logcat.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is logcat? There are no errors or anything that get thrown.

Comment: Logcat is a command-line tool which uses to see system messages
refer this https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

If you do have android studio installed., connect your device., view->Tool windows-> Android monitor.

Comment: oh, unfortunately I am not using Android Developer Studio. This is built in Corona SDK. Also, there are no errors or anything like that being thrown. It just isn't working on android.

Comment: Dude you can use Android Developer Studio to get the logs of your app made using Corona SDK. and also you can log that without using studio as well., you can refer the above link for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by changing the path to the file from

```
local btnpressSound = audio.loadStream( "/assets/Audio/FX/buttonpress.mp3" )
```

to

```
local btnpressSound = audio.loadStream( "assets/Audio/FX/buttonpress.mp3" )
```